AT Protocol SDK (atproto) added to Lambda Layer does not work
I have created a zip file with all the libraries on Amazon linux 2023 and uploaded it to LambdaLayer.
mkdir python

pip3.11 install atproto -t python

zip -r python.zip python

I then uploaded that zip file to LambdaLayer.
Then I created a Lambda, specified a Layer, and executed the code below, but it terminated with a timeout.
from atproto import Client, client_utils


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('test')
    client = Client()
    profile = client.login('MyBlueskyID', 'MyBlueskyPassword')
    print('Welcome,', profile.display_name)

    text = client_utils.TextBuilder().text('テストです')
    post = client.send_post(text)
    client.like(post.uri, post.cid)

Status: Failed
Test Event Name: posttest

Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2024-11-17T01:58:20.823Z xxxx-xxxx-xxxx Task timed out after 153.10 seconds"
}

Function Logs:
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10013.64 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout
2024-11-17T01:58:20.823Z xxxx-xxxx-xxxx Task timed out after 153.10 seconds

END RequestId: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
REPORT RequestId: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx    Duration: 153099.68 ms  Billed Duration: 150000 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB

Request ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

I set the timeout period to 150 seconds, but the situation remains the same.
I use Python version 3.11.
What is the cause of this and how can it be resolved?
I thought there was a problem with my long-time Amazon linux configuration for creating layers, so I started over by creating an EC2 instance, but that did not solve the problem.
And added a print function to see where in the source code it stopped, but it never output to CloudWatch.
I changed the Python runtime to 3.12, but the result did not change.

This has been resolved.
I set the memory setting to 256 MB, doing so allowed the process to complete in a few seconds.
The lesson learned is that we should start by reviewing the basic settings.
